# If first or last character from string is $ remove it in python

Tags: python

```
table_name='Customer$'
if table_name.startswith('$'):
    table_name=table_name[1:]
if table_name.endswith('$'):
    table_name=table_name[:-1]
```

I tried with the above code it gives me correct result as

```
 Customer
```

Is there any optimized way of doing it? please reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.strip()`:

```
table_name = '$Customer$'.strip('$')
```

This will remove all `$`s from the start and end and do nothing if there aren't dollars surrounding the string.

Comment: Not quite the same, unless the strings can start/end with at most one `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'$Customer$'.strip('$')
```

`strip()` method removes any leading (spaces at the beginning) and trailing (spaces at the end) characters (space is the default leading character to remove). By default trailing and leading spaces are removed. If an argument of character/s should be removed has been passed, then that character/s will be removed from leading and trailing poistions

Answer (score 0):

just use `.strip()` it works like `trim()`

```
table_name = '$Cu$$stomer$'
ans = table_name.strip('$')
print(ans)  # output Cu$$stomer
```

The `strip()` method returns a copy of the string by removing both the leading and the trailing characters (based on the string argument passed).

you can learn more about `strip()` from here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/strip